# How to solve this Connection GRPC Stream Error while trying to implement Authenticaton using Next-Auth with Firebase-Adapter

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to authenticate a user using next-auth with firebase as a backend.

Here is my [...nextauth].js file

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter"

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    emulator: {},
  }),
})
```

it shows **Sign in - Google Accounts** page then when I select a google account it just keeps in the loading state it shows No connection established error in the terminal.

Below is a picture that perfectly describes the error.

[Connection GRPC Stream error. Code: 14 Message: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No Connection established](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCeNZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the empty emulator object in the FirestoreAdapter. Removing it should solve the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).